# Conditionally add a new field to existing data in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

How to add a new field conditionally to my document?

current data in ElasticSearch

```
"_index": "test",
"_type": "logs",
"_id": "AWDgIKFCvg3odC71dRbc",
"_score": 0.09685399,
"_source": {
  "HighTH": 120000,
  "@timestamp": "2018-01-10T12:52:02.684Z",
  "Cust": 16926,
  "areaCode": 123
  "application": "myapps",
  "@version": "1",
  "host": "localhost",
  "Run_date": "2018-01-03T16:00:00.000Z",
  "LowTH": 10000,
  "message": "04-JAN-2018,MN,16926,206472,15785,120000,10000",
  "Trans": 206472,
  "Cntry_code": "NO",
  "Trans_GPS": 15785
}
```

i need to add a field "gpsStrength": 209845 into data only if "Cust" = 16926 and "areaCode" = 123.

the required result need to be

```
"_index": "test",
"_type": "logs",
"_id": "AWDgIKFCvg3odC71dRbc",
"_score": 0.09685399,
"_source": {
  "HighTH": 120000,
  "@timestamp": "2018-01-10T12:52:02.684Z",
  "Cust": 16926,
  "areaCode": 123
  "application": "myapps",
  "@version": "1",
  "host": "localhost",
  "Run_date": "2018-01-03T16:00:00.000Z",
  "LowTH": 10000,
  "message": "04-JAN-2018,MN,16926,206472,15785,120000,10000",
  "Trans": 206472,
  "Cntry_code": "NO",
  "Trans_GPS": 15785,
  "gpsStrength": 209845
}
```

I tried using index type and id which is updating the data

```
> POST test/logs/AWDgIKFCvg3odC71dRbc/_update?pretty { "doc": {
> "gpsStrength" : "209845" }
```

but required query based on _source values

i used dynamic mapping

Comment: I got a solution for this POST URL :  test/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed ;   Query :                                                                                                                           {
 "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.gpsStrength= 209845",
    "lang": "painless"
  },

  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "Cust": 16926 }}, 
        { "term": { "areaCode": "123"}} 
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: kindly suggest a way to do this in bulk